# Unable to map through node query data

Tags: reactjs, express

I managed to fetch my data through React on my node server however, when I simply try to map through it. It's telling me that the state that I set through my fetch is not a function. I looked online and map requires an array. However, upon inspection my fetched promise is indeed an array.

In addition, I'm using the necessary middleware on my server such as Bodyparser and CORS.

**Model**

```js
app.post('/myForm/:orderNum', function(req, res){
    request.query("SELECT [eUId], [GuestName], [STAY] AS UnitNum, [DELIVERY DATE] AS Delivery, [MoveInDate] AS MoveIn, [ReservedByEMail] as SendTo FROM [Test_Database].[Orders].[Order] WHERE [TableId] = '"+ req.body.orderNum +"'", function(error, results, fields){
        if(error){
            throw error;
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
        }
    });
    //console.log(req.body);
});
```

**View:**

```js
/*eslint-disable no-unused-vars*/

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Myform extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            errorMsg: "",
            orderNum: this.props.match.params.orderNum,
            theData: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        var data = {
            orderNum: this.state.orderNum
        }

        fetch('/myForm/:orderNum', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(theData => this.setState({theData: theData.recordset}));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
            // Unable to map through the fetched data? this is where I'm stuck
            {/* {this.state.theData.map(theData =>
                <ul>
                    <li key={theData.id}>{theData}</li>
                </ul>
            )} */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyForm;
```

Here is a screenshot of my returned promise the recordset is what I'm trying to map through.

[image]

Comment: are you getting an error? Or is the data simply not showing up on screen?

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to map through the data that was returned in my promise. Says this.state.theData.map is not a function.

Comment: that's because this.state.theData is not array, maybe theData is an object, can you log this.state.theData

Comment: I think you're right. When I log it, it logs the entire record set and every array/object contained inside of it. I'm not sure how I would just setState of the recordset in my theData.

Comment: what's the key that contains the array?, that's the one that you should set using setState theData.recordset.[KEY_THAT_POINT_TO_ARRAY]

Comment: plus check what is the full structure that `.then(res => res.json()) ` is giving you before setting the state, based on that decide that you need as state in your component

Comment: The screenshot that I sent is the full structure of res.json I'm going to keep playing with it.